# Javascript button, onclick function and alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a javascript element in my laravel site for decrease/increase quantity buttons. I want the quantity field to auto populate '0' in all of the input instances, and then obviously have the increase and decrease buttons add or subtract.

However, I can't get the input to populate with 0 on page load, and also, the input seems to have something above it that pushes the 'add' button down.

Here's my source code:

```
<div>
<button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
<input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;"  />
<button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success"  style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
</div>
```

Is there an obvious reason (I'm not well versed in JS) That the buttone is being pushed down and my field isn't populating with 0 or increasing/decreasing?

Comment: Add `value='0'` to make the input populate to a value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following style to all your buttons:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

This will ensure that padding does not affect the width of a button so that `width: 33%;` doesn't actually turn into `width: 33% + 14px;` etc.

To give an input a default value, you can either use `value='0'` or `placeholder='0'`

The value attribute will assign an actual retrievable value while placeholder will only show a value without actually assigning it. See the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o2u4m4jy/).

Comment: Thank you this works great for the value! It's still not increasing or decreasing on click though. Am I missing some JS code there?

Comment: Yes, you have not added any code to make it increase and decrease. Tip, in order to do it, you simply need to get the value of the input, add/subtract 1 from it and reassign the value to the input.